# Detecting Scroll event and do query for Fetching records from database according to screen size in android

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-sqlite

HI I have a Linear Layout with in a scroll view , I am adding a view in linear layout on run time, I have about 1000 records in database , i am creating a view for every record, and I am running a loop about 1000 times and adding that view with in that linear layout (with in scroll view ), when i do this , this takes so much time , about 30 seconds i think this is because i do some calculation on every record than i add that view and i am adding all 1000 records at a time , while there is no need add all record at a time ,

Now I think this problem can be solved only when I will add 5 to 6 view at a time ,and add more 5 to 6 view when user scroll that ,......

please give me some suggestion how can i solve this

Comment: any reason not to use a ListView?

Comment: you have to use list view adapter!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

I made an ArrayAdapter for a project I worked on a while back. Basically what it does is detect scrolls and loads more items down depending on your scroll location. That should be enough to get you started. There are still System.outs in there from testing. And of course in case you don't see right away this is an abstract class so you will have to build out your own retrieval methods. And likely alter this class to suit your needs.

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import com.example.epstest.http.APIClient;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AbsListView;
import android.widget.AbsListView.LayoutParams;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.AbsListView.OnScrollListener;
import android.widget.TextView;

public abstract class AsyncArrayAdapter<T> extends ArrayAdapter<T> implements OnScrollListener {
    private ArrayList<T> data;
    private int dataBufferSize;
    private int requestSize;

    private boolean loadingData = false;
    private MetaData metaData;

    public AsyncArrayAdapter(ListView listView, int dataBufferSize) {
        this(listView, dataBufferSize, new MetaData(0, 1));
    }

    public AsyncArrayAdapter(ListView listView, int dataBufferSize, MetaData metaData) {
        super(listView.getContext(), 0);
        data = new ArrayList<T>();

        this.dataBufferSize = dataBufferSize;
        this.metaData = metaData;
        listView.setOnScrollListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position < data.size() && super.isEnabled(position);
    }

    @Override
    public T getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(position >= data.size())
            return null;
        return data.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return data.size() + (loadingData ? 1 : 0);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if(position < data.size())
            return populateView(position, data.get(position), convertView, parent);
        // if this data element is outside the view then its the loading view. get and return it
        ProgressBar progBar = new ProgressBar(getContext());

        progBar.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        return progBar;
    }


    public void addItems(T[] items, MetaData metaData) {
        this.metaData = metaData;

        if(items.length >= dataBufferSize)
            System.out.println("Items of length [" + items.length + "] cannot be greater than the data buffer [" + dataBufferSize + "]" );

        for(int i=0;i<items.length;i++) {
            if(data.size() > metaData.offset+i)
                data.set(metaData.offset+i, items[i]);
            else
                data.add(metaData.offset+i, items[i]);
        }


        System.out.println("Added " + items.length + " items starting [" + metaData.offset + "] with max[" + metaData.max + "]"  );
        loadingData = false;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public void requestMoreItems() {
        if(!loadingData && metaData.getMax() > data.size()) {
            loadingData = true;
            requestMoreItems(data.size(), requestSize);
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }

    protected abstract void requestMoreItems(int index, int numItems);
    protected abstract View populateView(int index, T object, View viewToPopulate, ViewGroup parent);




    @Override
    public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
        if(firstVisibleItem + visibleItemCount >= totalItemCount - 1) {
            requestMoreItems();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
    }

    public MetaData getMetaData() {
        return metaData;
    }

    public ArrayList<T> getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public void setData(ArrayList<T> data) {
        this.data = data;
    }


    public static class MetaData implements Serializable {
        /**
         * 
         */
        private static final long serialVersionUID = -217672841165264339L;
        private int offset;
        private int max;

        public MetaData(int offset, int max) {
            this.offset = offset;
            this.max = max;
        }

        public int getOffset() {
            return offset;
        }

        public void setOffset(int offset) {
            this.offset = offset;
        }

        public int getMax() {
            return max;
        }

        public void setMax(int max) {
            this.max = max;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "MetaData[offset="+offset+", max="+max+"]";
        }
    }
}
```